# Error: Found 'T', required: '? extends Liquid'

Tags: java, generics

I have got some error trying to use basic generics. Below is a simplified version of the challenge;

```
public final class Example {
    private List<? extends Liquid> holder;
    private List<List<? extends Liquid>> holder2;

    public Example() {
        holder = new ArrayList<>();
        holder2 = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public <T extends Liquid> void add(int position, T value) {
        if (holder != null)
            holder.add(position, value); //<- Error Here
    }

    public <T extends Liquid> void add(int position, List<T> value) {
        if (holder != null)
            holder.add(position, value); //<- This works
    }
}
```

### Client

I want the variable holder to store different `subtypes` of Liquid. Example;

```
exampleInstance.add(0, new Water()); 
exampleInstance.add(1, new Juice());
```

Comment: The key insight here is that `List<? extends Liquid>` does **not** mean "a list of various subclasses of `Liquid`". It means "a list of various objects, that are all of the *same* subtype of `Liquid`, but I don't know which one specifically". If you understand that, the rest of the behavior here should make sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declaring your field with a upperbound wildcard : `List<? extends Liquid> holder` makes sense only if you would assign to a subclass of it or if you want to pass it in a method.
In this case, you cannot add anything but null in the List.

You are not in its use case. 
So instead of, declare     `private List<Liquid> holder` to be able to add  Liquid instances in your List.

Comment: I want the variable holder to have different subtypes of Liquid. Example; exampleInstance.add(0, new Water()); exampleInstance.add(0, new Juice());

Comment: And it will as you can add in a  `List<Liquid>` any `Liquid` instances (so Liquid or subclass of)

Comment: I am trying it out just a sec.

Comment: What is confusing is that in the same class, have another local variable like `private List<List<? extends Liquid>> holder2;` and it works this way with the wildcards. With the other local variable (without your solution) `private List<? extends Liquid> holderForSingle;` does not work. Why is it behaving differently? +1 for your solution.

Comment: Because the upperbound wildcard is not specified at the same level. So you don't have the same restriction. You cannot add no null elements in a `List<? extends Foo>` but you can in `List<List? extends Foo>>`

Comment: Ok, i get it now.